# localhost didn't send any data. in post service in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, express, kubernetes, microservices

I have working on  Microservices with Node JS and React (course from udemy) ,
but unfortunately I'm stuck with kubernetes problem
i have created posts-srv service,

posts-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

posts.js (index.js)

```
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
const posts = {};
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>
{
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true
    })
})
app.get('/posts',(req,res)=>
{
    res.send(posts)

})
app.post('/posts', async (req,res)=>
{

    console.log("app.post('/posts',(req,res)=> ")
    const id = randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
    const {title } = req.body;
    posts[id] = {
        id,title
    };
    await axios.post('htt://localhost:4005/events',{
        type:'PostCreated',
        data:{
            id,title
        }
    });

    res.status(201).send(posts[id])

})
app.post('/events',(req,res)=>
{
    console.log("received event",req.body.type);
    res.send({});
})

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log("server started for posts on 4000");

})
```

and the docker file is

```
from node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY ./ ./ 

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

then i used the command kubectl apply -f post-srv.yaml and service was successfully created but that is not accessible to my computer using browser

service details

```
Name:                     posts-srv
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=posts
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.108.229.174
IPs:                      <none>
Port:                     posts  4001/TCP
TargetPort:               4001/TCP
NodePort:                 posts  30095/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
```

I have accessed through the localhost:30095
but getting same error, please suggest some solutions

Comment: There's a mismatch in configuration and service details at least (port 4000, 4001)

Comment: `Endpoints: <none>` also is a problem, it suggests the Service's `selector:` doesn't match the Pod's `labels:`.  Depending on how you're running Kubernetes, the application may not be accessible from the browser via `localhost` at all.  What's the actual error?  What's in your Deployment spec?

Comment: i am deploying a basic microservice  app, localhost didn't send any data. in post service in kubernetes, this error pops up then i am accessing the  service, in the tutorial i just followed the same way but i am not getting and i have checked my code thrice @DavidMaze

Comment: @MikaVatanen ports are not the issue i have changed them but still getting this error

Comment: it would be nice and encouraging if any one spare 10 minutes i can share my github repo ,or help me though pc

Comment: Are you able to access your service through `localhost:4000` at least? if not, try changing `app.listen(...)` to just `app.listen(4000);` I ran into something where having anything else in the `app.listen()` would cause postman to return `Error: socket hang up`